# fields_for and accepts_nested_attributes_for in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fields-for, accepts-nested-attributes-for

I have noticed something strange. For I have a rails app which has user model.

User has one lab

Lab belongs to user.

User has two attributes , username and age.

Username is mandatory on creation and age is mandatory when updating.

I am using `fields_for` and `accepts_nested_attributes_for` creation of parent as well as child record in a single form.

Lab has four attributes:

`:first_reading, :second_reading` both mandatory on `create` , `:third_reading, :forth_reading` both mandatory on 'update'.

When creating an object, all my validations run on create, username for user and first_reading and second_reading for lab.

When editing the record, when my age is null, validation runs perfect, but when my lab's third and forth reading is null record is submitted. Why is this so? For user's age when blank, validation runs, and for lab's third and forth reading blank, validation doesn't run.

Is there any solution to this.

**WHEN CREATING:**
[image]
It shows the validation errors and the following are logs
Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2024-01-14 15:01:51 +0500
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML

Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"qgh9wx35JaqfAsRULMpBqp4rRlEeqhc8vVWzBkgoq2zV+AjN4WPnqR5l8Z/DUezHcc4UoyjEmAg/FmBoBfpikA==", "user"=>{"username"=>"", "age"=>"", "lab_attributes"=>{"igg_first_reading"=>"", "igm_first_reading"=>"", "igg_second_reading"=>"", "igm_second_reading"=>""}}, "commit"=>"Create User"}

(0.2ms)  BEGIN
(0.2ms)  ROLLBACK

**NOW AFTER FILLING ALL REQUIRED FIELDS OF BOTH MODELS, IT CREATES THE RECORD AND FOLLOWING IS THE LOG**

Started POST "/users" for ::1 at 2024-01-14 15:06:18 +0500
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"brSyTkjpUUkuDoYH0pOCWnnn1mTTgHhcd4V9yQQdPqwiod3WM5IIaU82yFZHPXWlFTgYue9cqhca8Efuzj8HZA==", "user"=>{"username"=>"ans", "age"=>"", "lab_attributes"=>{"igg_first_reading"=>"12", "igm_first_reading"=>"12", "igg_second_reading"=>"", "igm_second_reading"=>""}}, "commit"=>"Create User"}

(0.2ms)  BEGIN
↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:28
User Create (93.6ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("username", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3) RETURNING "id"  [["username", "ans"], ["created_at", "2024-01-14 10:06:18.084375"], ["updated_at", "2024-01-14 10:06:18.084375"]]
↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:28
Lab Create (204.8ms)  INSERT INTO "labs" ("igg_first_reading", "igm_first_reading", "user_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["igg_first_reading", 12], ["igm_first_reading", 12], ["user_id", 5], ["created_at", "2024-01-14 10:06:18.179247"], ["updated_at", "2024-01-14 10:06:18.179247"]]
↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:28
(16.1ms)  COMMIT

**WHEN UPDATING**

[image]

**while updating, it shows the user validation of age but not lab readings validation. here are the logs.**

Started PATCH "/users/5" for ::1 at 2024-01-14 15:07:29 +0500
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"4MKgZPXncHGvI/CilJIu8Ns8Qjl881XLBu0QunWZEKfeAJK1qtbKbBkK/gwGOR+u4sUT0Tws+LDq+UGsMzrLMg==", "user"=>{"username"=>"ans", "age"=>"", "lab_attributes"=>{"igg_first_reading"=>"12", "igm_first_reading"=>"12", "igg_second_reading"=>"", "igm_second_reading"=>"", "id"=>"5"}}, "commit"=>"Update User", "id"=>"5"}

User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:64

(0.1ms)  BEGIN
↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:41
Lab Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "labs".* FROM "labs" WHERE "labs"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:41

(0.1ms)  ROLLBACK
↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:41

**AND WHEN I ENTER THE AGE VALUE, IT SUBMITS THE RECORD.**

Started PATCH "/users/5" for ::1 at 2024-01-14 15:09:17 +0500
Processing by UsersController#update as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"+8rUqxJrMdoFrbjw5AZTfM8e/zdELcj1SNowy6EpF6mEOqGl7vHz2YTKjTsLnf4RIPutxXJDR8HKmeOl7PveVQ==", "user"=>{"username"=>"ans", "age"=>"8", "lab_attributes"=>{"igg_first_reading"=>"12", "igm_first_reading"=>"12", "igg_second_reading"=>"", "igm_second_reading"=>"", "id"=>"5"}}, "commit"=>"Update User", "id"=>"5"}

User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:64
(0.1ms)  BEGIN
↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:41
Lab Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "labs".* FROM "labs" WHERE "labs"."user_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["user_id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:41

User Update (0.3ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "age" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["age", 8], ["updated_at", "2024-01-14 10:09:17.208441"], ["id", 5]]
↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:41
(33.2ms)  COMMIT
↳ app/controllers/users_controller.rb:41

**NOTE =>** **WHEN UPDATING IF I CHANGE THE EXISTING VALUES OF LAB OR ADD ANY FIELD VALUE (THIRD OR FOURTH READING), THEN VALIDATION RUNS AND IT SHOWS ME ERROR AND IF I DONT TOUCH THE LAB RECORD, VALIDATION DONT RUN**

[image]
[image]

**This is my github repo link. You can go through the structure from here.
https://github.com/muhammadans414414/Demo**

Comment: too much text, sorry :-D please share your models, controllers and views.

Comment: While you have done a fantastic job of explaining your desired functionality and your current issue unfortunately without any code to go on we could only guess at why you might be experiencing this issue. Can you please post the following: User model and pertinent validations, Lab model and pertinent validations, the update action being used that is causing the concern.

Comment: I have added my github repo link. please go through guys when you get time. cheers

Comment: Please also share the log entries of the requests you send to the application. That will help us to understand what attributes and values you sent with what request.

Comment: And I noticed while looking at your repository, that you just started working in this application but that you created the application using outdated and unmaintained version of Ruby and Ruby on Rails. I suggest using current and if possible the latest versions when starting a new application and not versions that already reach end of life. At the time of writing, this means: Ruby 3.3.0 with Ruby on Rails 7.1.2.

Comment: @spickermann This behavior is same across versions.

Comment: I am still not sure if I understand your issue completely. But I guess that you are expecting behavior that could be enabled by adding [`validates_associated :lab`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.1.2/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates_associated) to your `User` model.